# Peugeot 206 suspected heater matrix leak

Tags: peugeot, coolant-leak, heater-core

Over the past few weeks, I've noticed large amounts of liquid on my passenger footwell (Peugeot 206). It happens infrequently and normally (AFAIK) overnight which led me to think its rainwater ingress.

Today I have decided to check my coolant levels while replacing the IACV and to my surprise, the reservoir was nearly empty! I took the glovebox compartment out to see if the leak is coming from the heater matrix.

While I can't see any leaks, there is a lot of yellowish residue. What do you think?[image: Residue around the heater matrix]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That buildup is definitely the sign of a leak, probably from the seal at that joint. It could have simply worked loose, or the seal could have degraded. If it was me I would drain the system, clean up that joint and replace the seal. There seems to be some buildup on the corner of the box as well, it's hard to say whether that's from the same problem. If it's a low point then it could be dripping down from the joint and collecting there, if not then it could be another leak. Try fixing that joint, if the leak stops then you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I finally got around to fixing it - wasn't difficult at all. I cleaned it up and replaced the o-rings, no leaks since.

Comment: Great news, I hope they are all that easy.